# Proof - A tree $T$ has a vertex of degree n and the others have degree $<n$. T has at least n leaves

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, trees

I tried to think about some characteristics of the trees, for example, they have a number of edges equal to $|\text{Vertices}|-1$ and of course the handshaking lemma but I couldn't find properly logical reasoning. Any help?

Comment: Hint: if you delete the vertex of degree $n$, then $n$ disjoint trees remain. How many leaves do each of those trees have?

Comment: @MikeEarnest sorry... i saw your comment after I posted my answer

Answer (score 3):

Let $v_i$ be the degrees of the vertices and suppose the graph has $v$ nodes.

Notice $\sum\limits_{i=1}^v (v_i-1) = v-2$

Without loss of generality $v_1=n$

This means $\sum\limits_{i=2}^v (v_i-1) = v-n-1$

So at least $n$ of the summands are equal to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let the tree be $T$, vertex with degree $n$ be $u$. Let the vertices adjacent to $u$ be $v_1, v_2,\cdots v_n$. Delete the vertex $u$. You'll get $n$ new components(trees), $T_1, T_2,\cdots T_n$. This is because no vertex in $T_i$ is adjacent to any vertex in $T_j$, $i\neq j$. WHY? Suppose they were adjacent. Let "that" vertex in $T_i$ be a, and in $T_j$ be $b$ $\implies$ you can go from $u$ to $a$, then $a$ to $b$ and then from $b$ to $u$$\implies$ cycle, which isn't possible. Hence, $T_i$s are components. Further, since $T$ was a tree, $T_i$s will also be trees.

Note that if $T_i$ has only a single vertex, it was already a leaf in $T$. Suppose there are $k$ such $i$$\implies $we get $k$ leaves from them $\implies $we need $n-k$ more leaves.      We need not consider "those" $T_i$s anymore. Finally, every tree has at least leaf, and $T$ has $n-k$ disjoint sub-trees, ( with $n(T_i)>1 )$  $\implies T$ has at least $(n-k)+k=n$ leaves!

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't understand the last part. It's clear that you can divide $T$ into $T_n$ components which are trees. It is not clear to me how you go from these considerations to saying that T has n leaves.

Comment: (1) Do you agree deleting u won't affect the number of leaves?

(2) Do you agree that every tree has at least one leaf?

(3) Do you agree that deleting u will lead to n (sub-)trees?

If it's all yes, you're done ;)

Comment: Apparently, everything is clear but I can not apply what I said to a simple example. For example, I have the tree 1-2-3 and the vertex 2 is connected to a vertex 4. So, if I delete the vertex 2 which has the maximum degree, I obtain the vertex 1,3,4 without the vertex 2 that they shared. How do I continue now?

Comment: I think if you want your proof to be complete, you should replace the phrase "every tree has at least a leaf" with "every tree has at least _two_ leaves." A leaf in $T_i$ might not be a leaf in $T$, if that leaf was originally joined to $u$.

Comment: Fixed everything now. Thank you for comments @MikeEarnest and PCNF